# Inserting "." in JavaScript string with str.replace()

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JavaScript string in "amount" which is in cents and I want to change it to $ by inserting a "." before the last two characters.  I seems like:

```
 amount.replace(/(..$)/,\.$1);
```

should do it, but it doesn't.

Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks

Comment: `.` is a regex metacharacter.  You'd need to escape it in the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replacement should be a string. It needs to be enclosed in quotes:

```
amount.replace(/(..$)/,"\.$1");
```

You could make it a little more robust by replacing the `..` which will match anything with `\d{2}` which will match 2 digits.

But if you input is only digits, it would be easier to convert it to a number and just divide it by `100`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to stay with the regex because it keeps everything in strings.  That seems easier than converting to a number, dividing by 10, and converting back to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var dollars = parseInt(yourString, 10)/100;
```

I can't see what is wrong with this that you are using regex here?

Comment: Unless there are some leading non-digit characters, I agree using a regex is silly when simple math will suffice.

Comment: @MattBurland yes then I think OP should do string manipulations to remove those non-digit characters and then divide by 100 as I shown. I really don't think using regex for adding decimal is good here. IMO. It is up to OP..